# evernote developer api user login and insert note

Tags: php, evernote

```
    <?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Evernote\Client(array(
  'consumerKey' => 'xxxx',
  'consumerSecret' => 'xxxxx'
));
$requestToken = $client->getRequestToken('index.html');
$authorizeUrl = $client->getAuthorizeUrl($requestToken['oauth_token']);


$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken(
  $requestToken['oauth_token'],
  $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'],
  $_GET['oauth_verifier']
);
$token = $accessToken['oauth_token'];

$client = EvernoteClient($token=$token);
$client = new Evernote\Client(array('token' => $token));

$noteStore=$client->getNoteStore();
$note = $Types->Note();
$note->title="I'm a test note!";
$note->content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE en-note SYSTEM "http://xml.evernote.com/pub/enml2.dtd">';
$note->content += '<en-note>Hello, world!</en-note>';
$note = $noteStore->createNote($note);

?>
```

I iam trying to login to user account and add note to there account.But i an not able to understand what is wrong.Can any one give code for my implementation .Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what error you got only from this code but Client->getRequestToken requires full callback URL (`http://yourdomain/path`) instead of just a file name.

You can see how it works [here](https://github.com/evernote/evernote-sdk-php/tree/master/sample/oauth). Especially, function.php might help.